# 500 internal server error ONLY if column is not null

Tags: php, mysql, internal-server-error

I am getting a 500 internal server error but only if I have certain MYSQL data columns set as not NULL.   In PHPMyAdmin, if I uncheck the "Null" box, I get the 500 error.  If not, I don't.    I just don't understand why this would be.   Why does it matter if it has a default value of null or not?  The affected values are q1right and q2right.   None of the others seem to be affected.  I have posted the PHP code below:

```
//set POST data as data to be inserted
$playername = $_POST['playername'];
$playerlastname = $_POST['playerlastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$coursename = $_POST['coursename'];
$period = $_POST['period'];
$quizname = $_POST['quizname'];
$score = $_POST['score'];
$numberofquestions = $_POST['numberofquestions'];
$q1right = $_POST['q1right'];
$q2right = $_POST['q2right'];

// Everything is cool -- Insert the data into the database


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $tname (playername,playerlastname,email,coursename,period,quizname,score,numberofquestions,q1right,q2right) VALUES (:playername,:playerlastname,:email,:coursename,:period,:quizname,:score,:numberofquestions,:q1right,:q2right)");

$stmt->execute(array(':playername' => ltrim($playername), ':playerlastname' => ltrim($playerlastname), ':email' => ltrim($email), ':coursename' => $coursename,':period' => $period,':quizname' => $quizname,':score' => $score,':numberofquestions'=> $numberofquestions,':q1right'=> $q1right,':q2right'=> $q2right));
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();     

// check if row inserted

 /* Return number of rows that were inserted */
 $count = $stmt->rowCount();
 echo ("$count");
```

Any thoughts on this are appreciated.   For some reason it doesn't insert q1right or q2right into the database either, whether I get the error or not.  I can't see any errors in the code but I'm probably missing something.

Also, nothing is showing up in my error logs in Cpanel.   Is there code I need to add to make this happen?

Comment: check the server logs for details about the 500.

Comment: and `$POST['q1right']` - you're missing the `_`. Since you didn't mention getting undefined variable/index errors, you're probably running with all debug options turned off. You should NEVER have `display_errors` and `error_reporting` disabled on a development system.

Comment: if your curious why that is happening as Marc mentioned, since `$POST` doesn't exist it does a null insert which when you allow for it will work fine, when you tell it not null however it fails.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the missing underscore after posting and fixed it on my script but it still did not work.    I updated the code above so the underscores are present.  Here is what I have for error reporting: $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8" , $user, $pass);
 $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

Comment: I'm using PDO.  How do I enable display_errors and error_reporting?  Is this in the PHP code or elsewhere?

Comment: You can set error_reporting  in php.ini file.

Comment: Thanks jathin,  do you know where on the server php.ini is normally found?   I can't seem to find it.   Does it need to be created from scratch?

Comment: I found a php settings in cPanel that allowed me to enable error reporting.   In cPanel, you just click on "Select PHP version" and then enable the extension you want under settings.   I hope this helps someone else who runs into this problem.  Thanks to everyone for your insights.